# Error parsing JSON using weather API in android

Tags: java, android, json, api, parsing

I am making a project which will get users current location when app is launched using FusedLocationProviderClient and then retrieve the weather for current location using weather API and display it in dummy text. Below is the code I provided. Its running the catch block of GetWeather method. which shows toast "error parsing JSON". Ignore the setlocation method as I only created it to assure that if its getting access to my current location and display the latitude and longitude in text view. I also have assured the API key and URL and location all are correct. I also ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,INTERNET permissions in manifest. Volley, glide and google play services location dependencies .
Please help me configure out where the problem is.
Thankyou in Advance

Comment: hello and welcome on stackoverflow. I think you forgot the code part.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.